# Como obtener el watch link de un video de youtube con python?

Tags: python, youtube, raspbian

me explico, he encontrado varias formas o librerías para hacer búsquedas en YouTube pero obtengo demasiados datos que no necesito y no sé como tratar después.
Sólo necesito el watch link, para después hacer un segundo script python que abra el navegador con ese link y reproduzca ese vídeo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Uso en raspbian.

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente que me devuelve un  diccionario con toda la info del video.

```
from youtubesearchpython import *

videosSearch = VideosSearch('tomorrowland', VideoSortOrder.accessibility, limit = 1)

busqueda = videosSearch.result()
```

Comment: Publica el código que has escrito hasta el momento, explicando que parte funciona, cual es la que necesitas y qué te impide lograrlo. Preguntas sin código son rápidamente cerradas.

Comment: Quizás esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/62780528/1264820 resuelva tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Esto es exactamente lo que buscaba. Ya lo he encontrado.

```
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch    
import webbrowser

videosSearch = VideosSearch('tomorrowland 2018', limit = 1)

for i in range(1):
    video = (videosSearch.result()['result'][i]['link'])
```